# ¿Cómo evitar los saltos de línea al solicitar que ingresen valores por teclado?

Tags: python, input

Cómo hago para que no se me genere un salto de línea cuando ingreso el otro valor sino que en la misma línea se pueda ingresar

```
print("Ingrese las coordenadas: ")
valor_1 = input()
valor_2 = input()
print(f"\n{valor_1},{valor_2}")
```

[image: Cómo hago para que no se me genere un salto de línea cuando ingreso el otro valor sino que en la misma línea se pueda ingresar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x, y, z = input("Teclea 3 valores: ").split() 
print("Valor 1: ", x) 
print("Valor 2: ", y) 
print("Valor 3: ", z) 
print()
```

Comment: GRACIAS!!! Es lo que buscaba.